# how to do the paggination using flsk and cosmosdb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I need to write a query to get values from the table for pagination so I'm using `WHERE` and `LIMIT`, `OFFSET` condition but I get an error or empty set

`SELECT * FROM v WHERE v._ts BETWEEN {} AND {}".format(value, value1)`

and

```
SELECT * FROM v ORDER BY v._ts ASC LIMIT {} OFFSET{}".format(value, value1)
```

I need records from value to value1. example I need no.of rows from a table with some limits

Answer (score 0):

Pagination in CosmosDb does not work like in a SQL/relational databases.

Generally, for the first request, you need run your query with filters and with a prespecified maxItemsCount (e.g. 10). The result is a collection of your entities and a `continuationToken`. For any consecutive requests, only need to send the `continuationToken` and the next 10 entites would be returned.

Here is a sample implemented in C#: https://github.com/pdhimate/WebApiBoilerPlate/blob/635d587759107dd795d1cc4221a31ca1ab960efa/Api.Data/CosmosDb/Repositories/CosmosRepoBase.cs#L76

Comment: I thought he said using flask not C#

Comment: Yes he did, but he is using LIMIT and OFFSET mechanism which isn't supported by CosmosDb.

Comment: So the answer to his question is that CosmosDB doesn't support this right?

Comment: Yes, CosmosDb supports pagination is a different way and not in the way he has mentioned in the question.